# Tool to convert python indentation from spaces to tabs?

Tags: python, indentation

I have a some .py files that use spaces for indentation, and I'd like to convert them to tabs.

I could easily hack together something using regexes, but I can think of several edge cases where this approach could fail.  Is there a tool that does this by parsing the file and determining the indentation level the same way the python interpreter does?

Answer (score 17):

If there are not many files to convert, you can open them in [vim](http://www.vim.org/), and use the `:retab` command.

See [the vim documentation](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/usr_30.html#30.5) for more information.

Answer (score 16):

Python includes a script for the opposite (tabs to spaces).  It's `C:\Python24\Tools\Scripts\reindent.py` for me

Comment: This is not available under Linux, even on py26.

Comment: stringvar.expandtabs(tabsize=8) is the opposite.   April 2018  v2.17

Answer (score 12):

:retab will swap tab with spaces, and :retab! will swap spaces with tab. 1 tab = 4 spaces, 4 spaces = 1 tab, depending on your tab setting.

Comment: +1, didn't know it worked both ways; it uses the `tabstop` setting, presumably?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Linux, you might also play around with [unexpand](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/unexpand.1.html):

> Convert  blanks  in each FILE to tabs,
>   writing to standard output.  With no
>   FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard
>   input.

Comment: You'll find a win32 build if you want.

Answer (score 3):

In emacs, `M-x tabify` will convert spaces to tabs where possible. You'll probably want to set the `tab-width` variable appropriately.

I don't know if this addresses your concern that spaces be interpreted in the same way as the python interpreter, but you could always load up python-mode and use `M-x indent-region`.